# Call to checkout URL redirecting to homepage

Tags: magento2, checkout, ajax

When adding a redirect to the checkout page in an Ajax `done` callback function, it seems to just go straight to the homepage instead:

```
}).done(function (data) {
    if (data.error) {
        console.log(data.error);
    } else if (data.success) {
        // take user to checkout if successful
        window.location = '<?= $this->getUrl("checkout", ["productid" => $this->getRequest()->getParam("productid")]); ?>';
    }
});
```

The thing is, this works as expected on a local environment and takes me to the checkout and I can access the `productid` parameter from there etc. but for some reason, on the release server it goes straight to the homepage.
The annoying thing is, there is nothing being reported in the server logs either so there is nothing to go off here.

Has anyone else came across this scenario before? and if so, how did you resolve it? :)

Cheers everyone!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be that there was a condition which was trying to re-direct the user to the /checkout/cart page, if the customer wasn't logged in. However the /checkout/cart controller was being overridden preventing the access to it and a result, the user was redirected to the homepage by default.

Cheers